# How to configure apache running in a Docker container

Tags: apache-httpd, docker

I am new in Docker and I have installed apache from the image httpd:2.4 and name tecmint-web. I am trying to configure apache but I have no idea how to do it. I tried the following steps:

*docker exec -it tecmint-web /bin/bash*

*ls*

*cd conf*

*ls*

And the ouput of the *ls* is : *extra  httpd.conf  magic  mime.types  original*
When I try to open httpd.conf with an editor, an error appears : *command not found*

I am doing anything wrong? How is it possible to configure apache?

Comment: `with an editor` what editor are you trying to use?

Comment: the correct way to configure apache in docker is as [documented](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)

Comment: In general, you do not start a container and start interactively changing config files. You create the config before hand and mount it into the container.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) of the official Docker image, to configure the Apache HTTP server, you can:

1. Copy the configuration file from the image to your host with:

```
docker run --rm httpd:2.4 cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > my-httpd.conf
```

2. Edit locally the `my-httpd.conf`
3. Build a new image, with the modified configuration file:

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Build the image with:

```
docker build -t my-configured-http-server .
```

You can also use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) with the original image and a mapped configuration file:

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-http-server:
    image: httpd:2.4
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/my-httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```